# React-router-dom links do not redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to include some links inside blocks...but it isn't working for me.
I wanna do this...[image: the part where says:"También podría interesarte"]
The Link tag is not redirecting....

```
const Relacionados = props => {
    const {items} = props;
    const links = items.map((item, index) =>
        <li key={index}><Link to={'/noticia-' + item.id}>{item.titulo}</Link></li>
    )
    return (
        <div className={'related bg-secondary'}>
            {items.length === 0 || <h4 className="text-white ml-3 intro">También podría interesarte...</h4>}
            <ul>
                {links}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The not shown part is this:

```
 <BrowserRouter>
     {entity === null || <NavbarErma entity={entity}/>}
     <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage2}/>
     <Route path="/noticia-:id" component={LeerNoticia}/>
 </BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found myself. This solved my trouble!!!

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if(this.props.match.params.id !== nextProps.match.params.id) {
            apiGET('/noticias/' + nextProps.match.params.id).then(items => {
                this.updateState(items.data, 'noticia')
            })
        }
    }
```